# Firefox is duplicating all of my mysql_query's

Tags: php, mysql, firefox

I have spent countless hours trying to figure out on my own why Firefox is doubling up on my queries. I have tested the code in Opera, IE and Chrome and it works fine. I will post in one of my smaller codes. I currently use a system that the selected page file includes 'header.php' at the beginning then includes 'footer.php' at the end.

I will just post a main page file, but if I should include my header and footer pages as well please let me know.

```
<?php $title = "Weapons Shop"; include("header.php"); ?>

<?php

if (!$buy) {
    print "Hello and welcome to the Weapons Shop, where you can buy anything from scrap metal weapons to high grade swords. <br><br><table>
    <tr><td width=120><b><u>Name</td><td width=100><b><u>Effect</td><td width=50><b><u>Cost</td><td width=50><b><u>Platinum</td><td><b><u>Level needed</td><td><b><u>Options</td></tr>";


$wsel = mysql_query("select * from equipments where type='W' and status='S' and owner=0 order by cost asc");

while ($wep = mysql_fetch_array($wsel)) {

    print "<tr><td>$wep[name]</td><td>+$wep[power] Defense</td><td>";
    $acost = $wep['cost'];
    $arcost = "".number_format($acost, 0,'.',',');
    print "$arcost</td><td>$wep[plat]</td><td>$wep[minlev]</td><td>- 
        <A href=weapons3.php?buy=$wep[id]>Buy</a></td></tr>";
}

    print "</table>"; 
}



if ($buy) {

$arm = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from equipments where id=$buy"));

if (empty ($arm[id])) {

    print "No such weapon. Go back to the <a href=weapons3.php>shop</a>.";

    include("footer.php");
    exit;
}

if ($arm[status] != S) {

    print "That's not a shop item. Go back to the <a href=weapons3.php>shop</a>.";

    include("footer.php");
    exit;
}

if ($arm[minlev] > $stat[level]) {

    print "Your level is too low for that! Go back to the <a href=weapons3.php>shop</a>.";

include("footer.php");
exit;
}

if ($arm[cost] > $stat[credits]) {

    print "You can't afford that! Go back to the <a href=weapons3.php>shop</a>.";

    include("footer.php");
    exit;
}

    $newcost = ceil($arm[cost] * .75);

mysql_query("insert into equipment (owner, name, power, cost, type) values($stat[id],'$arm[name]',$arm[power],$newcost),$arm[type]") 
    or die("Could not add weapon.");

print "You paid <b>$arm[cost]</b> credits, but you now have a new <b>$arm[name] +$arm[power]</b> weapon.";

mysql_query("update players set credits=credits-$arm[cost] where id=$stat[id]");
 } 
?>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

The problem in the case of this file is that with in Firefox, if a user buys a weapon then it creates 2 of the weapon, and charges the player twice as well.

I have found very few similar problems around the forums I found via google, and none that I found gave a sound solution to stop the problem. I have tried everything I can think of to fix this issue, and have gotten no where but the pharmacy for headache tablets.

Please help if you can!

EDIT:

in response to comments, I have below my 'header.php' and 'footer.php' and also 'config.php' as it is also involved.
**config.php**

```
<?php
mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("maindbinfo");
$cpass="";
$gamename="Rise of Kingdoms";
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<?php
    include("config.php"); 
    session_start(); ?>


<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['pass'])) {



$stat = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from players where user='$user' and pass='$pass'"));

if (empty ($stat['id'])) {

    print "Invalid login.";

    print "<META http-equiv=refresh content=4;URL=index.php>";


} } }


$ctime = time();

mysql_query("update players set lpv=$ctime where id=$stat[id]");

$ip = $_SERVER;

mysql_query("update players set ip='$ip' where id=$stat[id]");

mysql_query("update players set page='$title' where id=$stat[id]");

$remove_these = array("<", ">", "+","=" ,"-", "--");

function varscan($num) {

    global $stat;

    global $title;

    $remove_these = array("<", ">", "+","=" ,"-", "*");

for($b = 0; $b <= 5; $b++) {

        if (preg_match("/[$remove_these[$b]]/i", "$num")) {

            $fulltime = date("F j, Y, g:i a");

            print "!Alert! You have been caught trying to cheat, an admin will view what you have just 
                typed in and if it is a valid cheat or close to one you will be banned for an amount 
                of time depending on how many times you have tried... If you accidentally ran into this, 
                just mail id 1 by <a href=mail.php?view=write&to=1&re=Hacking:Accident>Clicking Here</a>. Thank you!"; 

        mysql_query("insert into adminlog (log, reason) values('Hacking Attempt<br>User: <b>$stat[user]</b><br>Id: <b>$stat[id]</b><br>
                IP: <b>$stat[ip]</b><br>Time: <b>$fulltime</b><br>Page: <b>$title<br>Script: <b>$num</b>','hacking')");

            $writeindoc = "Hacking Attempt<br>User: <b>$stat[user]</b><br>Id: <b>$stat[id]</b><br>IP: <b>$stat[ip]</b><br>Time: <b>
                $fulltime</b><br>Page: <b>$title</b><br>Script: <b>$num</b><br>---------------------<br>";

            $filename = "logs/hackinglog.htm";

        if (is_writable($filename)) {

                if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {

                    print "Could not open log file";

                exit;
}

                if (fwrite($handle, $writeindoc) === FALSE) {

                    print "Could not write to the log file";

                exit;
}

                fclose($handle);   

                }else{

                    print "Error with a log file";
}

        include("footer.php");

        exit;
}
 }

        return $num = str_replace($remove_these, "", "$num");

return $num = htmlspecialchars($num);

return $num = strip_tags($num); 
} 
?>



<head>
<title>Rise of Kingdoms</title>
<link rel=stylesheet href=style.css>
</head>

<body leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0 onload="window.status='Rise of Kingdoms | Version 0.1'">

<center>

<table width=98% valign=top class=td cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<td align=right bgcolor=DDCC71 style="border-bottom: solid 747d58 1px;">
<a href=irc://irc.netgamers.org/riseofkingdoms><b>IRC:</b> irc.Netgamers.org 
#RiseofKingdoms</a> <b>Game Time:</b> </b>
<? $date = date("h:i:s A T");   
print "$date"; ?> 
<b>Rise of Kingdoms</b> | Version 1.0 
</td></tr>
<tr><td><center><img src='banner.png'><br><b><a href=donate.php>Become a Donator to gain the 
upper hand over the rest</a></b><br><b><a href=vote.php>Please remember to Vote for Rise of Kingdoms</a></b></center>
<table>
<tr>
<td valign=top width=15%><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=td width=100%>
<tr><td style="border-bottom: solid 747d58 1px;" bgcolor=DDCC71 
align=center>
<b>Statistics</b>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>

<?php

print "<center><b><u>$stat[user]</b></u> ($stat[id])</center><br>";

print "<b>Level:</b> $stat[level]<br><br>";

$expn = (($stat['level'] * 62) + ($stat['level'] * 24));

$cexpn = "".number_format($expn, 0,'.',',');
$curexp = "".number_format($stat['exp'], 0,'.',',');    
$pct = (($stat['exp']/$expn) * 100);

$pct = round($pct,"0");

print "<b>Exp:</b> $curexp/$cexpn ($pct%)<br>";

print "<b>Health:</b> $stat[hp]/$stat[max_hp]<br>";

print "<b>Energy:</b> $stat[energy]/$stat[max_energy]<br>";

print "<b>Steps:</b> $stat[steps]/$stat[max_steps]<br><br>";

$credit = $stat['credits'];
$credits= "".number_format($credit, 0,'.',',');
print "<b>Credits:</b> $credits<br>";
$bank = $stat['bank'];
$banks = "".number_format($bank, 0,'.',',');

print "<b>Bank:</b> $banks<br>";

print "<b>Diamonds:</b> $stat[diamonds]<br>";

$plati = $stat['platinum'];
$platin = "".number_format($plati, 0,'.',',');  
print "<b>Platinum:</b> $platin<br><br>";

print "<b>Referrals:</b> $stat[refs]<br>";
        ?>

</td></tr>
</table><br>
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=td width=100%>
<tr><td style="border-bottom: solid 747d58 1px;" bgcolor=DDCC71 align=center>
          <b>Navigation</b>
    </td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-image: url('');
 background-position:  left bottom; background-repeat: no-repeat">

- <a href=stats.php>Overview</a><br>
        - <a href=equip.php>Equipment</a><br>

<?php

$numlog = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from log where unread='F' and owner=$stat[id]"));

print "- <a href=log.php>Log</a> [$numlog]<br><br>";
        ?>
<?php

if ($stat['town'] == 1) { print "- <a href=city.php>Silverlake (Town)</a><br>"; } 

if ($stat['town'] == 2) { print "- <a href=seccity.php>Shylock (Town)</a><br>"; }

if ($stat['town'] == 3) { print "- <a href=tricity.php>Falconview Peaks (Town)</a><br>"; }

if ($stat['town'] == 4) { print "- <a href=forcity.php>Maplehedge Crossing (Town)</a><br>"; }
?>
<?php

$king = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from kingdom where owner=$stat[id]"));

if ($king) {

    print "- <a href=kingdom.php>Your Kingdom</a><br>";
} 
else {
print "";
}
?>

- <a href=battle.php>Battle Arena</a><br><br>

<?php

if ($stat['tribe']) {

    print "- <a href=tribes.php?view=my>My Tribe</a><br>";
        }
        ?>

<?php



$edneed = ($stat['max_hp'] - $stat['hp']);

$itneed = ($edneed * 5);

$crneed = ($itneed * $stat['level']);

print "- <a href=hospital.php>Hospital</a> [$crneed cr]<br>";
        ?>

<?php

$mnumlog = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from mail where unread='T' and owner=$stat[id]"));

print "- <a href=mail.php>Mail</a> [$mnumlog]<br><br>";
        ?>

- <a href=bank.php>The Bank</a><br><br>

- <a href=forums.php?view=topics>Forums</a><br>

<?php

if ($stat['tribe'] > 0) {

    print "- <a href=tforums.php?view=topics>Tribe Forum</a><br>";
        }
        ?>

<?php

$psel = mysql_query("select * from players where page='Chat'");

$ctime = time();

while ($pl = mysql_fetch_array($psel)) {

    $span = ($ctime - $pl['lpv']);

    if ($span <= 180) {

        $numoc = ('$numoc' + 1);
    }
}

$numoc = ('$numoc' + 0);

print "- <a href=chat.php>The Pub</a> [$numoc]<br>";
        ?>

- <a href=irc://irc.netgamers.org/riseofkingdoms>IRC Chat</a><br><br>

- <a href=account.php>Account Options</a><br>

- <a href=logout.php>Log Out</a><br>

- <a href=help.php>Help</a><br>

<?php

if ($stat['rank'] == 'Staff') {

    print "<br>- <a href=news.php>Post News</a>";

    print "<br>- <a href=staff.php>Staff Options</a>";
}

if ($stat['rank'] == 'Staff') {

    print "<br>- <a href=sforum.php?view=topics>Admin/Staff Forums</a>";
}
        ?>

<?php

if ($stat['rank'] == 'Admin') {
    $anumlog = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from alog where unread='T'"));
    print "<br>- <a href=adminlog.php?view=adminlog>Admin Log [$anumlog]</a>";     }
if ($stat['rank'] == 'Admin') {

    print "<br>- <a href=admin.php>Admin Options</a>";
        }
        ?>

<?php

if ($stat['rank'] == 'Admin') {

    print "<br>- <a href=aforum.php?view=topics>Admin/Staff Forum</a>";
        }

        ?>

</td></tr>
    </table>
</td><td width=50% valign=top>

<?php

$jchance = rand(1,10000);

$jchance2 = rand(1,10000);

if ($jchance == $jchance2) {

    print "<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=td width=100%>";

    print "<tr><td style=\"border-bottom: solid 747d58 1px;\" align=center bgcolor=747d58><b>Juggernaut Vore</b></td></tr>";

    print "<tr><td>";

    $numj = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from core where name='Juggernaut' and owner=$stat[id]"));

    if ($numj <= 0) {

        print "You found the <b>Juggernaut Vore</b>! The most powerful default Vore in the game.<br>";

        mysql_query("insert into core (owner,name,type,ref_id,power,defense) values($stat[id],'Juggernaut','Secret',3,10,10)");

    } else {

        print "You found the <b>Juggernaut Vore</b>! It's jealousy of your other Juggernaut makes it leave in a huff.";
}

    print "</td></tr></table><br>";
    }
    ?>

<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=td width=100%>

<tr><td style="border-bottom: solid 747d58 1px;" bgcolor=DDCC71 align=center>

<?php 
        print "<b>$title</b>"; ?>

</td></tr>
        <tr><td>
```

and this is my footer.php

**footer.php**

```
</td></tr>
</table><br>
<br>
</td><td width=15% valign=top>

<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=td width=100%><tr>
<td style="border-bottom: solid 747d58 1px;" bgcolor=DDCC71 align=center>
<b>Storage</b>
</td></tr><tr><td>

<?php

print "<center><b><u></b></u></center>";

print "<b>Rats Tails:</b> $stat[ratt]<br>";

print "<b>Chicken Feathers:</b> $stat[chickf]<br>";

print "<b>Wolf Hairs:</b> $stat[wolfh]<br>";

print "<b>Hunters Arrows:</b> $stat[hunta]<br>";

print "<b>Witches Brooms:</b> $stat[witchb]<br>";

print "<b>Cobra Fangs:</b> $stat[cobraf]<br>";

print "<b>Dragon Scales:</b> $stat[drags]<br><br>";

if ($stat['mines'] > 0) {

    print "<b>Burelia:</b> $stat[burelia]<br>";

print "<b>Alethite:</b> $stat[alethite]<br><br>";

        }

if ($stat['flicence'] >= 1) { 
print "<b>Carp:</b> $stat[carp]<br>"; }

if ($stat['flicence'] >= 2) {
print "<b>Saratoga:</b> $stat[saratoga]<br>"; }

if ($stat['flicence'] >= 3) { 
print "<b>Largemouth Bass:</b> $stat[bass]<br>"; }

if ($stat['flicence'] >= 4) { 
print "<b>Lobster:</b> $stat[lobs]<br>"; }


$test = (($stat['level'] * 135) * ($stat['level'] * 2));
print "$test";

if ($stat['refaward'] == 'Y') {
if ($stat['level'] >= 5) { 
    print " ";
    mysql_query("update players set diamonds=diamonds+10 where id=$stat[referred]");
    mysql_query("update players set refaward='N' where id=$stat[id]");
    mysql_query("update players set refwin=refwin+1 where id=$stat[referred]");
    mysql_query("insert into log (owner, log) values($stat[referred],'<b>$stat[user] ($stat[id])</b> has reached level 5. 
        Your 10 Diamonds have been recieved.')"); } 
else {
    print " "; } }
        ?>


</td></tr></table><br><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=td width=100%><tr>
<td style="border-bottom: solid 747d58 1px;" bgcolor=DDCC71 align=center>

<b>Online Players</b>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>

<?php

$psel = mysql_query("select * from players order by id asc");

$ctime = time();

while ($pl = mysql_fetch_array($psel)) {

$span = ($ctime - $pl['lpv']);

if ($span <= 500) {

    if ($pl['rank'] == 'Admin') {

        print "<img src=images/admin.gif>";
}       

    if ($pl['rank'] == 'Staff') {

        print "<img src=Tiny_S.gif>";
    }                   

    print "<a href=view.php?view=$pl[id]>$pl[user] ($pl[id])</a>";                  
    if ($pl['sub'] > 0) {

        print "<img src=http://www.renhelp.net/images/tutorials/star.gif>";
} 
    print "<br>";       

}
}

    print "</td></tr>
</table><br>
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=td width=100%>
<tr>
        <td style='border-bottom: solid 747d58 1px;' bgcolor=DDCC71 align=center>

        <b>Game Stats</b>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
";  
    $nump = @mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from players"));

    $numo = ('$numo' + 1);
    $numw = @mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from equipment where type='W'"));

    $numa = @mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from equipment where type='A'"));

    print "<b>$nump</b> total players.<br>";

    print "<b>$numo</b> players online.<br>";

    print "<b>$numw</b> weapons.<br>";

    print "<b>$numa</b> armor.<br>";            
?>

</td></tr></table><br>
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=td width=100%><tr>
<td style="border-bottom: solid 747d58 1px;" bgcolor=DDCC71 align=center>

<b>Vote for Rise of Kingdoms</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>

<?php


print "Please vote using these links to help promote and support this game. For each vote you will receive <b>1 Diamond</b>. 
The more you vote, the more people see the game, and therefore the more people join and make the game more enjoyable!
<br><br>";


if ($stat['vote'] == 'N') {

print "<a href=vote.php?vote=1>Top 100 Arena</a><br>"; }

if ($stat['vote2'] == 'N') {

print "<a href=vote.php?vote=2>Top 50 Onrpg</a><br>"; }

if ($stat['vote3'] == 'N') {

print "<a href=vote.php?vote=3>Top Game Sites</a><br>"; }

if ($stat['vote4'] == 'N') {

print "<a href=vote.php?vote=4>GTOP 100</a><br>"; }

if ($stat['vote5'] == 'N') {

print "<a href=vote.php?vote=5>Game Sites 100</a><br>"; }

if ($stat['vote6'] == 'N') {

print "<a href=vote.php?vote=6>Ultimate Top 200 Game Sites</a><br>"; }

if ($stat['vote7'] == 'N') {

print "<a href=vote.php?vote=7>PHP Games Network</a>"; }


?>


</td></tr>
</td></tr></table>
<center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First things first... don't echo HTML.

Comment: this is pure server side code, firefox cannot hacve anything to do with that. But your frontend may accidentally fire this code twice, or maybe post some parameters wrong. My suggestion is add some logs, so you can check how many times this code run with what parameters, and analyze that to see whether you have problem in your backend or frontend.

Comment: what is the content of 'header.php' and 'footer.php'?

Answer (score 1):

> I have spent countless hours

I wonder why it takes so much time to just monitor all the **HTTP requests** issued by the browser, especially if that browser happen to be Firefox, with it's countless web-dev tools.
the most famous among them - Firebug can show you all the requests made with it's `Net` tab, so you can see extra ones and take necessary precautions (most likely it would be preventing the code from executing SQL queries upon request of favicon.ico file).